# Constraints created as NO CHECK are getting created as CHECK after publishing the dacpac

Tags: database, visual-studio, constraints, database-project, dacpac

I was publishing my dacpac solution into a database. What i am seeing after the publish is that the constraints that were dropped and re-created in the publish process is created as CHECK constraints.

On Googling about the issue i found that there was a property called "**Script Validation For New Constraints**" which is responsible for making all the new constraints into CHECK. So i tried setting that property to false and published again. Now the issue is that all the constraints are created as NOCHECK.

Any help on how can i preserve the CHECK or NOCHECK state of these constraints.?
Also why Visual Studio DACPAC solution is creating all constraints as NOCHECK and setting it to CHECK at the end.?

Definition of Constraint in the Database before Publish

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[table_name]  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [ck_table_name_ssn] CHECK  (([ssn] is null or [ssn] like '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'))
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[table_name] CHECK CONSTRAINT [ck_table_name_ssn]
GO
```

Definition of the Constraint in the Database after Publish

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[table_name]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [ck_table_name_ssn] CHECK  (([ssn] is null or [ssn] like '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'))
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[table_name] CHECK CONSTRAINT [ck_table_name_ssn]
GO
```